# Browse for xlsx workbook and create a drop down list to select a sheet to read

Tags: pandas

I am absolutely new to python and I am trying to build a code that will upload a data frame based on the browsed xlsx file and then drop down list of all sheets in the selected xlsx file.

I have found two codes: one for browsing and reading excel file and second for drop down list with all sheets in selected xlsx file. What I need to do is actually to combine this two codes. First of all I would like to select an xlsx sheet and then I would like to select which sheet to read (based on drop down list).

## Function to browse and read excel file

`enter code here`import tkinter as tk
`enter code here`from tkinter import filedialog
`enter code here`import pandas as pd

```
root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'white')
canvas1.pack()

def getExcel ():
    global df

    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df = pd.read_excel(import_file_path, sheet_name='Loan Tape')
    df.keys()
    df
    root.destroy()

browseButton_Excel = tk.Button(text='Import Excel File', command=getExcel, bg='yellow', fg='black', font=('arial', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=browseButton_Excel)

root.mainloop()
```

---

## Function to create a drop down list of all sheets in the xlsx file

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Select a sheet")

mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S) )
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.pack(pady = 100, padx = 100)

tkvar = StringVar(root)

xl = pd.ExcelFile(r'Full file path.xlsx')
choices=xl.sheet_names
tkvar.set('Nothing selected') # set the default option

popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *choices)
Label(mainframe, text="Select a sheet").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column =1)

def change_dropdown(*args):
    print( tkvar.get() )
    root.destroy()

tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown)

root.mainloop()
```

What I need to do is to actually combine this two codes. First of all I would like to select an xlsx sheet and then I would like to select which sheet to read (based on drop down list).

Comment: Please specify what exactly your problem is, what have you tried so far etc.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to build some simple interface that will:
1) Allow the user to browse the excel file
2) Allow the user to select a sheet from excel file (e.g. based on drop down list)
3) Read this sheet as a data frame
I have found two codes but I can't combine them.